# NoClassDefFoundError for otherwise available class

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I'd like to run WsImport directly with the `java` command. I'm using the following command (with CLASSPATH environment set up):

```
$ java com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport -d /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebFormsTest/build/generated-sources/jax-ws -Xendorsed -keep -B-jaxb-facets -wsdl -r /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebFormsTest/build/generated-sources/jax-ws/resources -s /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebFormsTest/build/generated-sources/jax-ws -verbose org.czentral.test.service.AdminService
```

And get the error message in the title. With all the details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1058)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at com.sun.istack.tools.MaskingClassLoader.loadClass(MaskingClassLoader.java:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:363)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:952)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:374)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument(Options.java:692)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:326)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:232)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.parseArguments(WsimportTool.java:359)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:193)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:135)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:57)
```

Ok, this far a reasonable explanation would be a missing `.jar` from classpath. But I actually have the right jar, which is confirmed with the following:

```
$ java com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin
Error: Main method not found in class com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

So the classloader actually **can** load the class.

*What condition can result in an error like this?*

Answer (score 0):

This is a platform specific issue. Code was compiled in a platform resulting in a platform specific jar, and then, although the class and the jar exist in your classpath, java does not recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not only basing my diagnosis of the `.class` being visible in the `.jar` file. Please note that in the last code block the *class loader* successfully loads the class (and reports that it has no *main* method).

Answer (score -1):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

Read more at: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz2ILpyqUVe

Comment: Thank you, I'm well aware what the exception says. Please read the last few paragraphs of my question.